# draw contours on red plate image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, contour

Hi I am working on a program that requires to find the contours of the license plate,  everything was fine for the license plates but when I try to get the contours of the red plate it doesn't show the contours properly, I check  all the result of converting the image to gray then blur the image and then threshold the image to implement the find contours and these are the images:

original image :

[image]

gray scale image :

[image]

image thresh :

[image]

find contours :

[image]

as  the image shows, I want to get the contours around the Arabic numbers but the threshold around the number is white and black inside so it's not surrounding them perfectly

just like this image :

[image]

This is my code for the  processing of the two images:

```
image = cv2.imread('red_image3.jpg')

gray_image = extractValue(image)

imgMaxContrastGrayscale = maximizeContrast(gray_image)


imgBlurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgMaxContrastGrayscale, (3,3), 0)

imgThresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imgBlurred, 255.0, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,
                                  17, 9)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(imgThresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for contour in contours :
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    cv2.rectangle(image , (x,y) , (x+w,y+h),(0,255,0), thickness=1)
```

Comment: Thresholding would not give you a good result. Try MSER feature extraction and some morphologic operation to get what you want. Opencv has a good implementation of MSER.

Comment: @Meisam do you have any links that could help me in it iam still new to the field

Comment: Just google it: MSER opencv python.

Comment: hi sorry to bother you 
I tried the MSER method as you suggest and it works great but the method return overlapping rectangle 
do you know a way to eliminate the overlapping ones  
@MH304

Comment: Try separating the box of each number, with the information of it's size. Height/width ratio of each number in LP is fixed, so you can manage to extract them with this fact.